# Old machine title fonts

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typesetting

I am searching for a font that was/is used to title machines, for example in the image below where it says "Machine 9" and "Debris Data Feed".

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think we've all seen this font at least once near engineering, machinery, architecture, etc environments... I'm trying hard to dig the name out of my memory, in vain.

In the meantime i use a font called [Miso](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/miso), that does look fairly similar in it's all caps version.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That could be the [DIN Family](https://www.fontshop.com/families/ff-din) which is and has been used extensively in industrial and public signage applications.

[image]

Comment: Looks pretty close, it may be the condesed version of this.